# How control "system sounds" volume (NOT Masetvolume) of windows?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, system-sounds

i have certain problem, since i am using a custom windows design (retro), which comes with wallpaper, cursor icons and sounds for Windows system sounds like alert or closing windows.
(Basically simple stuff)

Now i got the problem my "System Sounds" in the Mixer keeps reseting back to 100, and i dont know where to start, since i cant see a pattern here, something keeps resetting it!

So i thought i make little programm which constantly sets it back to 30 and maybe Notify me , so i can see somehow a pattern. (It drives me nuts!)

I saw many solution here, but not about "System Sounds Volume settings", i dont want change the master volume of my speakers/soundcard! Just the setting for volume of "System alert/window closing".